# for each ID keep the track of the status change and update the end date in r

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, lapply, sapply

I have the below dataframe where for each `LO_SEQ_NO` I am trying to keep track of the `CEL_IND` whenever there is a change. I want to create the new columns such as `status` and `ST_END_DATE` and I want to update the `ST_END_DATE` and `status` to the first record where the `LO_SEQ_NO` started and the rest filled with NA
Input:

```
"SEQ_NO" "CREATION_DATE" "CEL_IND"  "LO_SEQ_NO"
1        2015-11-13          O          358
1        2015-05-13          O          478
2        2015-06-17          O          478
3        2015-07-30          N          478
4        2015-07-30          O          478
5        2015-08-23          O          478
```

Expected output:

```
"SEQ_NO" "CREATION_DATE"  "ST_END_DATE" status     "CEL_IND"  "LO_SEQ_NO"
1        2015-11-13             NA      NA          O           358
1        2015-05-13     2015-06-17       O          O           478
2        2015-06-17             NA      NA          O           478
3        2015-07-30     2015-07-30       N          N           478
4        2015-07-30             NA      NA          O           478
5        2015-08-23             NA      NA          O           478
```

I implemented the below code from there I am not able to extract the information what I need. Is there any way I can get help to use the generated relation in order to obtain the final expected output.

```
loan_test$CEL_IND<- as.factor(loan_test$CEL_IND)
          loan_test$CEL_IND <- as.integer(loan_test$CEL_IND)
          loan_test$CEL_IND[loan_test$CEL_IND == 1] <- 0
          loan_test$CEL_IND[loan_test$CEL_IND == 2] <- 1

          loan_test$ci <- with(loan_test, as.integer(c(FALSE, CEL_IND[-length(CEL_IND)] - CEL_IND[-1]) !=0))
          loan_test$lse <- with(loan_test, as.integer(c(FALSE, LO_SEQ_NO[-length(LO_SEQ_NO)] - LO_SEQ_NO[-1]) !=0))



     "SEQ_NO" "CREATION_DATE" "CEL_IND"  "LO_SEQ_NO" ci lse
      1        2015-11-13          O          358     0  0
      1        2015-05-13          O          478     0  1
      2        2015-06-17          O          478     0  0
      3        2015-07-30          N          478     1  0
      4        2015-07-30          O          478     1  0
      5        2015-08-23          O          478     0  0


lse <- which(loan_test$lse == 1)

          lapply(1:length(lse), addColLse)
          addColLse = function(x){
            ci = which(loan_test$ci == 1)
            lse_lower = if(length(lse) > 1) lse[x-1] else 0
            ci_sub = ci[which(ci >= lse_lower && ci <= lse[x])]
            ci_sub
            lapply(2:length(ci_sub), addStuff)
          }

          addStuff = function(x){
            loan_test$ST_END_DATE[x - 1] = loan_test$CREATION_DATE[x]
            loan_test$status[x - 1] = loan_test$CEL_IND[x - 1]
          }

Getting below error
          Error in loan_test$ST_END_DATE[x - 1] <- loan_test$CREATION_DATE[x] : 
           replacement has length zero
```

I would be thankful if you could help me with this.

My Main goal if for each `LO_SEQ_NO` I have series of transactions whenever `CEL_IND` status changes I want to copy the `CREATION_DATE` before changing from `O` to `N` or any other state and store it in   `ST_END_DATE` for `CEL_IND` status `O` when it was started for the first time in `CREATION_DATE` for `LO_SEQ_NO`  was `2015-05-13` before changing from `O` to `N` `CREATION_DATE` is `2015-06-17`

Comment: Can you explain your procedure a little better? You say you are *"trying to keep track of the `CEL_IND` whenever there is a change?"* It seems like "keep track of" means *put the value in a new column, called `STATUS`, which is otherwise `NA`*. But what does "whenever there is a change" mean? A change in what? I thought maybe it was whenever `CELL_IND` changes, but in the `SEQ_NO` 4 it changes from N to 0 and is not recorded. I thought maybe it has something to do with `IND_CHANGE_DATE`, but again `SEQ_NO` 4 matches the change date but `CELL_IND` is not recorded. So what do you want to do?

Comment: @Gregor I updated the question if you need more information let me know

Comment: @Gregor any suggestions